# OutOfMemoryError stack trace guaranteed to be source?

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I am running into an OutOfMemoryError in a library inside my app. The stack trace points to a line inside the library where start() is called on a new thread. The error looks like this:

Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create(1040KB stack) failed: Try again

The error is not reliably reproduce-able, it happens maybe once out of 300 launches.

If the stack trace points to a line inside the library, does that automatically mean the problem lies there, or could there be memory leaks in the application, and Java just happened to run out of memory at the same time that we hit that line of code in the library? I don't want anyone to try and solve the problem, I just want to know if I for sure need to look at the library, or if this just means there is a memory issue somewhere in the app.

Thanks!

Comment: Post your whole exception and some code to explain.
What are you doing that is causing an OOM? Are you using a low-end device?

Comment: The stacktrace will tell you where you couldn't get more memory; not why (no, it's not necessarily where your **problem** is). A profiler should be able to help you find the *actual* problem.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll make a new question if I need help figuring out where the actual problem is. Just wanted to confirm the problem could be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> or could there be memory leaks in the application, and Java just happened to run out of memory at the same time that we hit that line of code in the library?

Yes, that's pretty much it. The library could still be the source of the error, though, but you can't tell for sure from the stack trace.